# What's the standard practice to listing clients you've worked with through an agency

Tags: business, portfolio, resume

What's the standard practice, within a portfolio site or resume, to list clients you've worked with through an agency?

Since the agency is technically your client, is listing the agency's clients under "Clients I've worked with..." an accepted practice? I believe it may be more appropriate to word it as "Brands I've worked with..." because it addresses the work, not the relationship.

Comment: What, specifically, are you asking about? What context? And are you just questioning about the phrasing of it or whether or not it can be done at all?

Comment: Edited in response to @ZachSaucier's question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

What you put on your personal portfolio and what you have on your resume won't necessarily be the same. A portfolio and a resume are not the same thing and serve different purposes.

For example, you may have work in your portfolio as:

> **Project X for Brand Y**
>   *<sub>Completed whilst working at agency Z</sub>*

And work listed in your resume as:

> **Worked for Agency X**
>   *<sub>Completed projects including project Y for brand Z</sub>*

---

Before you do any of that though, you should find out if there is anything in any contract between you and the agency, you and the client or any other contract between any party involved that affects what you can claim and publish. It's a *very* good idea to talk to the agency first. You'll probably then have your answer. Otherwise...

Do whichever sounds better, depending on what you want to convey. Wether that is just listing the brand, listing the project and brand "whilst working at agency X", or just listing the agency and letting the work speak for itself (i.e. if this is in your portfolio).

Basically you should do whatever is most beneficial to you, without misleading or being dishonest—or more importantly, breaking any contractual agreements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend caution if you're listing the agencies' clients as your own - in fact one of the agencies I'm working with has asked me to sign an NDA to stop me from doing this. Although technically yes you've produced work for those clients, you didn't win that business yourself - only working on it by proxy through the agency who did all the hard work of pitching etc.

It's generally fine to say that you've worked for an agency and give *their* name, and anyone who wants to look into it can then guess/find out what sort of brands you'd be working on within that agency. However even then I'd ask the agency's permission as some (again in my experience) do not want it widely known that they use freelancers/which freelancers they use (in case any of their clients decide to jump ship and go to you directly for a lower price).